# First and Last names in a table do not match with ID's

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hello everybody here is my issue. (TRANSACT-SQL)

I have two tables, Table 1 is my main table, and it has all Student ID's, and the first and last names associated (StudentID, First Name, Last Name)

Table 2 has students with failing scores. The issue is, The first and last names of students are NOT matched with any ID's, as in, the entire studentID column is blank(Full of NULL values, because it is blank). (The first and last names are correct, and are in table 2)

How do I write some sort of a query(or update) to permanently fill this column in with the correct ID's. (Again, the first name, last name, and matching ID columns are available in table 1)

If it is easier I can merge the first and last name column, but I would prefer to leave them that way.

Thank you!

Comment: This is bad design.  If Student IDs are your unique identifier, the table that stores students with failing scores should be set up with a field for Student ID to tie it to a specific student.  This is called a "foreign key" in your table of failing scores - it points to the 'primary key' of Student IDs in your table of students.  And except in rare cases, student first and last names should not be stored in any table except the table that defines students.  This is called 'database normalization.'

Comment: Well, yes, I am aware of keys and such, be they primary or foreign. This is actually what I am trying to set up.

The thing is, this is an exercise that my buddy has given me of a sample database that is messy for me to fix. So it is intentionally designed badly. The issue I was having was only that I need to fill this column in. I am also aware of database normalization, having taken the Microsoft database essentials course. I am planning on doing that after I fix this, and a couple more issues. 
I really appreciate the input, I should have mentioned that I knew these concepts earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` query with a `FROM` to join your tables. The big caveat here is that this will break if you have more than one person sharing the same name.

```
UPDATE t2 
SET t2.id = t1.id
FROM table2 as t2
     INNER JOIN table1 as t1
        ON t2.firstname = t1.firstname AND
           t2.lastname = t1.lastname
```